# How to Save the data from a GridView to SQL Server 2005? How to Edit and Delete rows in the Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, gridview

I have a GridView containing data extracted from two TextBoxes on click of a button. I want the following functionalities to be implemented in the Gridview:
1) I want to be able to Edit the data in this GridView. 
2) I should also be able to Delete the rows from the GridView.
3) Finally, when I click on another Submit button, all the rows from the Gridview should be saved in the database.

Its a web-based ASP.NET application coded using C# (Visual Studio 2010), and uses SQL Server 2005.  How can I make changes to the below code to implement the above specified functionality?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["constring"]);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            dt = Session["data_table"] as DataTable;
        }
    }

    protected void btnTextDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        if (dt == null)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name");
            DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("City");
            dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc2);

            Session["data_table"] = dt;
        }

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = txtName.Text;
        dr[1] = txtCity.Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        gvDisplay.DataSource = dt;
        gvDisplay.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ds.Clear();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("insert into PRACT values(@name, @city)", con);
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        gv.DataSource = ds;
        gv.DataBind();
        con.Close();        
    }   
}
```

Comment: Check this `http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anjudidi/select-update-and-delete-data-in-a-Asp-Net-gridview-control/`

Answer (score 0):

Well on your aspx page I would recommend you to do that:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="gvDisplay" OnRowCommand="grid_OnRowCommand">
  <Columns>
  <TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtNameGrid" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </TemplateField>
  <TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtCityGrid" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "City")%>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </TemplateField>
  <TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnDeleteGrid" Text = "Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval(Container.DataItem, "YourIDColumn")%>' CommandName="DeleteRow"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I recommend you to create a new column in your DataTable, this column will be the ID of each register.

Well, you add registers to this DataTable on your page, so you will need to create a session of type int and each time the event btnTextDisplay_Click is called you must increase this int Session and set it's value to the DataTable's Column ID.

The grid's attribute, OnRowCommand, is the event that will be called when you click on the button btnDeleteGrid. The code of this event comes below:

```
protected void grid_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.CommandName == "DeleteRow")
   {
      foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
         if(Convert.ToInt32(row["YourColumnID"]) == Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument))
            row.Delete();
      }

      dt.AcceptChanges();

      gvDisplay.DataSource = dt;
      gvDisplay.DataBind();
   }
}
```

Your event that will save the registers should be like that.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["constring"]);
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

     cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE_NAME (NAME, CITY) VALUES (" + row["Name"].ToString() + "," + row["City"].ToString() + ")";

     int numRegs = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

I really expect I helped.
I can't test my code and I'm not so good on work with DataTables, so if there's any problem with my code, just let me know.

I think it will be more efficient if you use Bulk Inserts to realize the inserts. Search for how to make it, it's pretty cool and quick.

And also try to use Stored Procedures, because it's safer than use direct command texts. Using them will prevent SQL Injection.

Best regards.